# Auto-Compare Archives Beyond Compare 4

Tags: chm, beyondcompare

I am using `Beyond Compare 4` to compare two folders. One folder contains the `actual output` from a script I wrote and the other one contains the `expected output`.

The thing is that those two folders contain a bunch of `.chm` (a type of archive) files and I have to click on each file every time to compare their contents.

I found [this article](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?sessiondirhandling.html) describing that you have to open the archives files to compare their contents.

Is there a way to automatically do that?

Comment: From a command line run `hh.exe -decompile {output directory name} {file name}.chm`. Replace `{...}` with appropriate names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on the [site](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?sessiondirhandling.html) you mentioned already:

> ## Archive handling (e.g. zip files)
>
> **As folders always** treats archive files like regular folders.

This way will `Beyond Compare` always automatically unpack archives before comparison.

Don't forget to change it in session defaults (select `Also update session defaults` in checkbox at the bottom of dialog) so that it will be applied also next time you will do comparison.